# Create login Accessible by particular machine(s)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like do such login page that will Allow me to login from only My Office PC and Home PC.

any other PC will not allow me to login even Password and username is correct.

I have gone through the Mac Address. But It is giving me Server's Mac Address. not giving request sender's Mac Address.

I have also think about IP Address. But It may common for other PC. and It can be change.

Do any one know what should I do as my application in asp.net ?

Comment: You need to explain our environment a little better, where is your office / home pc and web server located, same LAN, across Internet? Sounds like you need authentication and/or ip address filtering

Comment: It is not in a LAN. My Question is require to use based on Machine. I can accessible via only my both machine only. If I use any other machine then It will not allow me.

Comment: In that case ip address is useless. There is nothing specific to a machine in a web request. So the machine needs something that identifies it uniquely, that no other machine has. (mac address can be spoofed). Client certificates installed on permitted machines will mean only those machines can access your application and is the way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SSL already configured you can set "require client certificates" and install corresponding certificate to machines you want to connect from.

How to [configure IIS 7 for to use client certificates for SSL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753983%28v=WS.10%29.aspx).